# Comparing two characters in a string/array to see if they are the same

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, non-repetitive

I am trying to create an array and remove the repetition except for the spaces (" "). I have seen some of the methods online, but I'm trying to do it without copying. I've tried many ways but I just don't understand why my methods don't work.

This is what I've tried:

In the first one the methodology is to receive input, call function, create an arraylist, traverse through the string whilst adding each character to the arraylist, traversing through the list a second time to compare each character to the character at the first index, checking if they are equal then removing them from the arraylist

The issue seems to be "checking if they are equal then removing them from the arraylist" :

```
if(character.get(i).equals(character.get(k))) {
    character.remove(arr.charAt(i));                
}
```

And for the second one

```
for(int k = 0;k < characters.length;k++) {
    if(characters[i]==characters[k]) {
        System.out.print(character);                        
        character.remove(characters[i]);                    
    }
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class NoRepeats {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a phrase: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        
        char[] characters = chars(input);
    }
    
    public static char[] chars(String arr) {
        ArrayList<Character> character = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length();i++) {
            character.add(arr.charAt(i));           

            for(int k = 1; k<arr.length();k++) {
                if(character.get(i).equals(character.get(k))) {
                    character.remove(arr.charAt(i));                
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(character);
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class NoRepeats {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a phrase: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        //receive input
        char[] characters = chars(input);
        //call function
    }
    
    public static char[] chars(String arr) {
        ArrayList<Character> character = new ArrayList<Character>();
        //create an empty arraylist
        char[] characters = arr.toCharArray();
        
        for(int j = 0; j<characters.length;j++) {
            character.add(characters[j]);
        }
       
        for(int i = 0; i<characters.length;i++) {
            /*traverse through the orignal array adding a character to 
            the empty array list each time*/            
                for(int k = 0;k < characters.length;k++) {
                    if(characters[i]==characters[k]) {
                    System.out.print(character);                        
                    character.remove(characters[i]);                    
                }                   
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Expected input:

```
“And I think to myself: what a wonderful world!”
```

Expected output:

```
And I thk o myself: w ru !
```

The first one produces this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
at NoRepeats.chars(NoRepeats.java:20)
at NoRepeats.main(NoRepeats.java:10)

The second one produces this error:

"Exception  in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 118 out of bounds for length 2
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:504)
at NoRepeats.chars(NoRepeats.java:33)
at NoRepeats.main(NoRepeats.java:11)
"

Comment: Hi there! To help us better understand the issue, could you please add more details? For compilation errors, [edit] the post, include the error message and highlight the problematic code. For exceptions, [edit] the post, include the stack trace and highlight the triggering code. For unexpected behavior, [edit] the post and provide a [MRE] with expected and observed output. Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic: If you are willing to rethink your approach, and code it anew, you might consider that some methods that already exist are useful.  Here is a link to the [`ArrayList` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: You are trying looking for duplicates while populating the list, which cannot work. After the first iteration, the list contains a single entry and you try to compare it with a second entry that does not yet exist. Better use sets(LinkedHashSet as the order is important), then you don't have to worry about the duplicates yourself

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you! I have added those, I did highlight the triggering code in the beginning

Comment: One problem in your first approach is the way `ArrayList#remove` works. Except when the element to be removed is the last element, removing an element causes the positions of all the other elements to be shifted by one. So, by  using `for` loops, when an element is removed, the shift can cause the following element to be skipped over.  Although it likely doesn't apply here, removing an element this way risks a `ConncurrentModificatinException` . The approved way to remove elements from an `ArrayList` is to use an `Iterator` .

Comment: See the [`ArrayList` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: When running your code produces an exception, please include a copy of the stack trace that should follow. The stack trace includes source code line numbers. Find the lines referring to your source code. The top one will be the one where the exception was triggered. Highlight that line in the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Instead of adding an element, and then checking if it is a duplicate, try checking if it is a duplicate first. If it is a duplicate, don't add it.

Comment: For someone who regularly develops software, debugging will be a necessary skill.  These links might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems  and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer is this okay?

Comment: Yes, thank you. A minor point: It would help to show stack traces as a blocks of code.

Comment: The first points to lines 10 and 20 in your code. Line 20 triggers the exception, and is probably this one: `if(character.get(i).equals(character.get(k))) {` Now, ask yourself "What could be wrong with the value of `k` in that line?"

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer It's that it's out of bounds? I think it may be that it's starting at a index that doesn't exist yet? And thus only ends up comparing it to the ones before and the one after and not the whole thing?

Comment: In the inner `for` loop, the index variable, `k`, runs from zero to the length of the array, `arr`.  But, it is used to index elements of the `character` List. So, if `arr.length > character.size ()`, boom --  you get an exception. You want to limit `k` to the size of the list, not the array.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Thank you, I'm glad you're still up. I did try swapping out the "arr.length" for "character.size" before and i got this exception under the inner for loop bracket: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 110 out of bounds for length 2
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
 at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:504)
 at NoRepeats.chars(NoRepeats.java:21)
 at NoRepeats.main(NoRepeats.java:10)
I can't post the full on

Answer (score 2):

First need to formulate your algorithm in words (or kind od pseudocode). Something like this:
Problem: remove duplicated chars from string except space.
Solution (pseudocode):

```
output_string = ""
used_chars = ""
for (c : input_string) {
  if (c == ' ') output_string += c;
  else if (!used_chars.contains(c)) {
    output_string += c;
    used_chars += c;
  }
}
print(output_string)
```

Now you can implement this in any language you want.
Implementation in java can be:

```
static String solution(String input_string) {
    String output_string = "";
    Set<Character> used_chars = new TreeSet<>();
    for (char c : input_string.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == ' ') output_string += c;
        else if (!used_chars.contains(c)) {
            output_string += c;
            used_chars.add(c);
        }
    }
    return output_string;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(solution("And I think to myself: what a wonderful world!"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
package app;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoRepeats {
    public NoRepeats(){}

    public String scan(){
        System.out.print("Please enter a phrase: ");
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String read = scanner.nextLine(); //receive input
        scanner.close(); //do not forget to close
        
        return read;
    }

    public int contains(String character, char c, boolean caseInsensitive){
        int N = character.length();
        
        if(caseInsensitive) c = Character.toLowerCase(c);

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            char next = character.charAt(i);
            if(caseInsensitive) next = Character.toLowerCase(next);
            
            if(c == next) return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public String getChars(String arr) {
        String character = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
            char next = arr.charAt(i);

            if(Character.isWhitespace(next) || contains(character, next, true) == -1) character += next;
            //else; //ignore
        }

        return character;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NoRepeats noRepeats = new NoRepeats();

        String input = noRepeats.scan(),
               chars = noRepeats.getChars(input);

        System.out.println("String: " + chars);
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
And I think to myself: what a wonderful world!
```

**Output:**

```
String: And I thk o myself: w  ru !
```

Answer (score 1):

You're indexing your `ArrayList` with `i` from the character array which is increasing in magnitude faster that the size of list. So you are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException.`

- I suggest you use a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet()) to keep track of duplicates.
- Initialize a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to hold the result
- If the character is not whitespace.

  - then add it to the set.  If that returns false, it has been seen before so continue to the end of the for loop.
  - otherwise, add the character to `StringBuilder` if it is the first time seen. Since non-letter characters will never be added to the set, they will always be added to StringBuilder.
- When done, return the array of chars.  If you want to return the string instead, just do `return result.toString()` and change the method signature to return type `String`.

```
public static char[] chars(String arr) {
    Set<Character> seen = new HashSet<>();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : arr.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch))
            if (!seen.add(Character.toLowerCase(ch))) {
                continue;
            }
        
        result.append(ch);
    }
    return result.toString().toCharArray();
}
```

Here is how it might work.

```
String input = "And I think to myself: what a wonderful world!";
char[] result = chars(input);
System.out.println(new String(result));
```

prints

```
And I thk o myself: w  ru !
```